# Открыть активити не по кнопке

Tags: activity, android, java

в интернете есть множество примеров как создать и открыть активити.
но все они открываются по нажатию на кнопку.
возможно ли открыть активити не по нажатию на кнопку? если да, то как это сделать?
не из главного класса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо передать в ваш класс context. Например, при создании класса new MyClass(this);

В конструкторе класса сохраняете этот контекст и передаете его в интент:

```
public class MyClass {

    Context context;

    MyClass (Context c){
        context = c;
    }

    public void func() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, My.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Либо можно передать контекст через параметр метода, если не хотите через конструктор класса передавать:

```
public class MyClass {

    public void func(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, My.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: но ведь теперь он будет ругаться на startActivity

Comment: потому-что класс из которого я хочу открыть активити не наследуется от Activity.

Comment: Точно, забыл. Запускать в этом случае вот так

    context.startActivity(intent);

Comment: извиняюсь за нубство, но каким образом мне передать контекст из главного активити в класс? func(General.getApplicationContext()); или как?

Comment: func(this);

Comment: The method func(Context) in the type GetSend is not applicable for the arguments (GetSend) :(

Comment: Вот нашел на stackoverflow кусок кода. Попробуйте так.

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{   

      Intent startActivity = new Intent();  
      startActivity.setClass(context, xxx.class); 
      startActivity.setAction(xxx.class.getName()); 
      startActivity.setFlags( 
              Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK 
              | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS); 
      context.startActivity(startActivity); 

}

Answer (score 1):

Ну по сути у вас повешен обработчик на кнопку, который и создает новую автивити, что мешает перенести код из этого обработчика в любой другой обработчик, не обязательно кнопки? событий же много

Comment: код должен выполниться не в обработчике.
Intent intent = new Intent(General.this, Add.class);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: нужно указать this.
если написать GetSend.this - ругается.
GetSend - класс из которого мне нужно открыть активити.

Comment: объект intent в конструкторе должен содержать 2 параметра: контект и имя класса. главное активити - расширяет класс Activity, поэтому мы в первом параметре конструктора интента указываем "нашкласс.this". но если я хочу вызвать открытие активити из другого класса, то не понимаю как быть..